# How to change line in Ext.MessageBox message?

Tags: javascript, extjs, messagebox

How to change line in Ext.MessageBox message?

```
if (duplicatedRecords.length > 0) {

    var msg = '';

    duplicatedRecords.forEach(function(element) {
        msg += ' - ' + element.get('ClientName') + '\n';
    });

    Ext.MessageBox.show(
    {
        title: 'Record(s) already exists',
        msg: msg,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        closable: false
    });

}
```

I've tried with '\n' and doesn't work...

[image]

Comment: In the dialog image, it looks like you're using `/n` instead of `\n`. Is the framework you're using changing them or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is rendering HTML, so you can just add a 'br':

[Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/aki)

```
Ext.MessageBox.show(
{
    title: 'Record(s) already exists',
    msg: "msg<br/>msg",
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
    closable: false
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Message is just and HTML, so you can use `<br>` if you want to do it manually.

If your text is big it will automatically wrap your text.